# Email output of script

Tags: email, powershell, output

I'm trying to email the output of a script, but I'm pretty sure I have my syntax all mixed up.

Here what I'd like:

```
send-mailmessage -from " Daily Check <server@company.com>" -to "Admin <admin@company.com>" -subject "Daily Check: Server Times" -body $output -priority High -dno onSuccess, onFailure -smtpServer mail.company.com

$output=

{
ForEach ($server in $servers) {
    $time = ([WMI]'').ConvertToDateTime((gwmi win32_operatingsystem -computername $server).LocalDateTime)
    $server + '  ' + $time
    }        
}
$servers = 'SVRADFS365', 'SVRAPP01', 'SVRCAS01', 'SVRCAS02
```

The original script whose output I want emailed:

```
$servers = 'server1', 'server2', 'server3', 'server4'
ForEach ($server in $servers) {
    $time = ([WMI]'').ConvertToDateTime((gwmi win32_operatingsystem -computername $server).LocalDateTime)
    $server + '  ' + $time
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Got it working...

If you get the error:

```
Send-MailMessage : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Body'. Specified method is not supported.
At line:11 char:150
+ ... r Times" -body ($output ) -priority High -dno onSuccess, onFailure -smtpServer m ...
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Send-MailMessage], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage
```

Add: `-body ($output | Out-String)`

Answer (score 1):

You must create `$output` before sending your email by `send-mailmessage` cmdlet.

Try with this code:

```
$servers = 'SVRADFS365', 'SVRAPP01', 'SVRCAS01', 'SVRCAS02'
$output = ForEach ($server in $servers) {
            $time = ([WMI]'').ConvertToDateTime((gwmi win32_operatingsystem -computername $server).LocalDateTime)
            $server + ' ' + $time
          }

send-mailmessage -from " Daily Check <server@company.com>" -to "Admin <admin@company.com>" -subject "Daily Check: Server Times" -body $output -priority High -dno onSuccess, onFailure -smtpServer mail.company.com
```

Comment: I tried what you recommended, it works, but the ForEach only runs once. 

'
$servers = 'SVRADFS365', 'SVRAPP01', 'SVRCAS01', 'SVRCAS02'
$output=
"{
ForEach ($server in $servers) 
 {
    $time = ([WMI]'').ConvertToDateTime((gwmi win32_operatingsystem -computername $server).LocalDateTime)
    $server + '  ' + $time
    }
}"
send-mailmessage -from " Daily Check" -to "Admin" -subject "Daily Check: Server Times" -body $output -priority High -dno onSuccess, onFailure -smtpServer mail.company.com'